# MongoDB - Query collection and related collection and match fields in both collections (Aggregation)

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have the following collections, where Account is related to the Company collection. The reference is stored as accountId.

Company

- name
- accountId

Account

- email

Now I want to query both collection like that

```
db.getCollection('Company').aggregate([
                  { $lookup: { from: 'Account', localField: 'accountId', foreignField: '_id', as: 'account' }},
                  { $unwind: '$account' },
                  { $match : { $or: [{ name : /example/, 'account.email' : /example/ }] } }
             ])
```

In the end it should return all companies where the query matches the company name and also all companies where the query matches the related account.email (even when the company name is not matched at all). But my problem is that the $match is preventing that.

So for example companies with the following data should be returned.

- name: Example Inc, account.email: mail@mail.com,
- name: Example Corp, account.email: corp@corp.com,
- name: Different Inc, account.email: example@example.com

How do I have to adjust the aggregate method to retrieve the data like this?
Thx!

Comment: your query seems fine can you elaborate what is the response coming if above query is executed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try using regex like mentioned below. since you are trying a like query.

```
db.getCollection('Company').aggregate([
              { $lookup: { from: 'Account', localField: 'accountId', foreignField: '_id', as: 'account' }},
              { $unwind: '$account' },
              { $match : {$or:[{name: {$regex: "example", $options: "i"}}, {"account.email": {$regex:"example", $options: "i"}}]} }
         ])
```

Comment: Just what I was looking for, only how should I do it when I have several collections referenced in the source table? Because if I do this for each collection, the query would not return anything, since it would expect to meet each of the filters, right?

Comment: You can add multiple lookup in same pipeline of the source table refering to each collection.
you can refer this https://www.mongodb.com/community/forums/t/complex-aggregation-with-multiple-lookups-unwinds-results-in-nested-arrays/136856